# How to select a div that has no identifier, using Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-selectors, greasemonkey

I need to remove a div, but it doesn't have an identifier (class, id) I can use to select it.

This is the div:

```
<div style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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%3D%3D&quot;); z-index: 99998; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 5809px;"></div>
```

Is there any way to select this div with Greasemonkey?

Comment: Is it  always in the same order? You could select all divs and then grab the nth div from that.

Comment: No, not always in the same order unfortunately.

Comment: Is it possible to select something based on the css background-image value?

Comment: Not sure. You could select all divs, then iterate over them and check the background-image property, maybe? Or, check if said property exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The div might have a fixed code-position relative to some more selectable element.
- If the div doesn't have a unique CSS path, it might have a unique
  XPath. (Except you state that it's not always in the same order in
  this case.)
- If the background image is always the same, you can select it by that.  EG:

  ```
  var badDiv  = document.querySelector (
      "div[style*='iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC']"
  );
  badDiv.parentNode.removeChild (badDiv);
  ```

  Or with jQuery:

  ```
  $("div[style*='iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC']"). remove ();
  ```
- Alternatively, selecting on the `position: absolute; top: 0px;` part of the `style` attribute.
- Finally, the div might have unique content you can use. (Not shown in this question.)

Comment: I used suggestion #3, with jQuery, and it worked perfectly. The last 2 suggestions wouldn't work because other elements have the same positions, and the DIV is actually empty with just the background image.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've been fooling with this for an hour or so now, haha.